# Compare Data in Two Tables

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have two tables that I need to compare to make sure the values match. For context, one is the employee's time sheet and the other is a table to holds their requests. Each has a time sheet code and a number of hours. My plan was to compare by summary to see if they match. However, I am having problems getting my logic to work perfectly every time. Without me posting my code (it is becoming a mess quickly anyway), how would you approach this? The comparison needs to be able to be run programmatically and in the end return a true/false.

This can be an RPG solution or a SQL solution.

This is what I need to make sure is true.

```
Table 1
02  1.5
04  16.0

Table 2
02  1.5
04  16.0
```

The problem is when

```
Table 1
02  1.5

Table 2
02  1.5
04  16.0
```

or when

```
Table 1
02  1.5
04  16.0

Table 2
02  1.5
```

or more so when

```
Table 1
02  1.5
04  16.0

Table 2
```

Comment: Please at aleast give us the table structures of the two tables and sample data and  the expected result set.

Comment: the hour count needs to match for rows in each table with the same timesheet code?

Comment: Added some examples of errors and what I need to make sure is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put my two SQL results into views then based on many peoples feedback already came up with this. I think this could be created into it's own stored procedure.

```
SELECT SUM ( ERROR_COUNT ) AS TOTAL_ERRORS INTO NUM_ERRORS FROM (
SELECT COUNT ( * ) AS ERROR_COUNT
FROM MPRLIB . V_TSHOURSUMM A EXCEPTION JOIN MPRLIB . V_REQHOURSUMM B
ON A . EM_NUMBER = B . EM_NUMBER AND A . TIMESHEET_CODE = B . TIMESHEET_CODE AND A.HOURS_SUMMARY = B . HOURS_SUMMARY
WHERE A . EM_NUMBER = EMPLOYEE_ID OR B . EM_NUMBER = EMPLOYEE_ID
UNION
SELECT COUNT ( * ) AS ERROR_COUNT
FROM MPRLIB . V_REQHOURSUMM A EXCEPTION JOIN MPRLIB . V_TSHOURSUMM B
ON A . EM_NUMBER = B . EM_NUMBER AND A . TIMESHEET_CODE = B . TIMESHEET_CODE AND A . HOURS_SUMMARY = B . HOURS_SUMMARY
WHERE A . EM_NUMBER = EMPLOYEE_ID OR B . EM_NUMBER = EMPLOYEE_ID ) TABLE
```

It seems to work, but seems... excessive. Thoughts? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

This will compare the total hours in A and B for each ID value, and only return records there the sum of B does not equal A.  It treats unmatched values of B as zero.

```
SELECT A.id, A.hours, SUM(COALESCE(B.Hours,0))
FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B
  ON B.ID = A.ID
WHERE 1=1
  AND A.id = B.id
GROUP BY A.id
HAVING A.Hours != SUM(COALESCE(B.Hours,0))

Cheers,
Daniel
```

Answer (score 1):

This should give the requested results:

```
with w1 ( wid, sumHrs )
 as ( SELECT id, sum(hours)
        FROM A   a1
        GROUP BY id ),
     w2 ( wid, sumHrs )
 as ( SELECT id, sum(hours)
        FROM B  b1
        GROUP BY id )
 select '1', w1.wid from w1 INNER JOIN w2 
                                on w1.wid = w2.wid
                      where w1.sumHrs <> w2.sumHrs 
union
 select '2', w1.wid from w1 EXCEPTION JOIN w2 
                                on w1.wid = w2.wid
union
 select '3', w2.wid from w2 EXCEPTION JOIN w1 
                                on w2.wid = w1.wid
```

There might be minor detail changes needed due to adapting and simplifying from a sample I have that's close but not exact. All of the basic concepts should be clear, though.

The CTE gives a couple summary "views" for use in the full statement. The `INNER JOIN` gives matching IDs with mismatched HOURS. The first `EXCEPTION JOIN` gives rows from the first table with no matching ID in the second table, and the second `EXCEPTION JOIN` gives rows that aren't matched in the other direction. And the `UNIONs` collect all results together.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you merge two tables, and the count of the resulting table is the same as the count of the individual tables, you can say that they have the same values.

I am not sure how to apply in your case, but maybe you can.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution show lines that are in conflict:

```
CREATE TABLE requests ( employees_id integer, hours decimal );
CREATE TABLE hours ( employees_id integer, hours decimal );

SELECT * FROM requests, hours WHERE requests.employees_id = hours.employees_id AND requests.hours != hours.hours;
```

But it doesn't work if e.g. one 2h request needs to match two 1h markings.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this recently - here are my notes... the result set shows differences in values plus rows that are present in one table but not the other.

Step1: Create temporary tables containing the rows you want to compare.

Step2: Perform a FULL OUTER JOIN on the temp tables using the non aggregate columns as matching criterion.

```
DECLARE @Ta TABLE (PubA varchar(255), CampA varchar(255), RevA money)   

INSERT INTO @Ta (PubA, CampA, RevA)                     
    SELECT Publisher, [Campaign Name], SUM([Revenue USD])               
    FROM D1.dbo.Stats               
    GROUP BY Publisher, [Campaign Name]

DECLARE @Tb TABLE (PubB varchar(255), CampB varchar(255), RevB money)   

INSERT INTO @Tb (PubB, CampB, RevB)                     
    SELECT Publisher, [Campaign Name], SUM([Revenue USD])               
    FROM D2.dbo.Stats                   
    GROUP BY Publisher, [Campaign Name]

SELECT PubA, CampA, RevA, PubB, CampB, RevB, RevA-RevB DiffRev  
FROM @Ta                        
FULL OUTER JOIN @Tb                     
ON PubA=PubB and CampA=CampB                        
ORDER BY DiffRev DESC                       
GO
```